# Windows 7 Administrative Shares

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I'm having trouble enabling administrative shares for all Administrators.

I've enabled File Sharing as well as added the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry key like all of the "solutions" out there tell you to do.

This works great for the Administrator account, but not any other Administrator.

The only way to make it work for all Administrators is to disable UAC.

Is there any way around the last step?  I don't want to disable UAC unless I really have no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was only able to get this to work by turning off UAC.

Answer (score 1):

To resume all the steps required to use administrative shares in Windows 7:

1. Define the network type as Home or Work
2. Turn on File and Printer sharing
3. In regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, and add add a new DWORD named `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` and give it a value of 1
4. Disable the HomeGroup (in Control Panel / Network and Internet / HomeGroup, click Leave the homegroup).

Administrative shares should work if all these steps were done.

Comment: This is not the case.  This only works if UAC is off.  I've tried both ways and it only works when UAC is off.